# SQL 'ab,cd' compared with 'cd,ab' is true

Tags: sql, postgresql, preg-match

I have a little situation in postgresql

I have two tables t1 and t2 and both have a column with same type of data 'col_data',
col_data may have only following data ('ab', 'cd', 'ab,cd', 'cd,ab')

I want to return TRUE when a compare t1.col_data and t2.col_data when t1.col_data='ab,cd' and t2.col_data = 'cd,ab'

Comment: This is one of the many reasons why you should *not* store comma-separated data in text fields. See http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/55871/7788

Comment: I know that very well, also, this is why, as employer, you should not give a project to an outside team and later expect your own team to edit the project.

Comment: Hehe, I've experienced that pain before (as the "inside team" component).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right solution is to *fix your data model* so you don't store composite data as comma separated values in a text field; see [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/55871/7788).

The short term workaround is probably to define a "commasep_to_sorted_array" function, something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION commasep_to_sorted_array(text) RETURNS text[] AS $$
SELECT array_agg(t ORDER BY t) FROM regexp_split_to_table($1,',') t;
$$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

then use it in your comparisons:

```
commasep_to_sorted_array(t1.col_data) = commasep_to_sorted_array(t2.col_data)
```

Needless to say, this isn't usefully indexable. Though you could create an expression index that'd be useful in some cases.

If your case is really as simple as you describe, with only four possible values, you could probably convert the column to an enum:

```
CREATE TYPE abcd AS ENUM (
   'ab', 'cd', 'ab,cd', 'cd,ab'
);

ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN col_data TYPE abcd USING (col_data::abcd);
```

(though I really hope the real names are more informative than this!)

If you really treat them as two independent flags, so the value can be "neither ab nor cd", "just ab", "just cd", or "both ab and cd", then you should model them that way instead - two boolean fields, a bitfield, or an int field you manually test bits in. I'd prefer two boolean fields without a good reason to do otherwise.